# Compare rows containing varying length road subsections attributes with set of fixed subsection lengths?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following dataframe listing sections of a road (defined by start and endpoints in km format) that contains attrivutes for varying subsections. The length simply derives from the start-end-points.

```
Start   End     Attrib  Length
0       0.03    K       0.03
0.03    0.036   K       0.006
0.036   0.082   K       0.046
0.082   0.091   H       0.009
0.091   0.096   H       0.005
0.096   0.1     K       0.004
0.1     0.121   K       0.021
0.121   0.123   K       0.002

...
...
```

What i need is to find and possibly create a new dataframe for

a) the most common attribute per each 0.1km-section and

b) its percentage of the total 0.1km-section.

What i have so far is a list of the 0.1km-section in the form of tuples. I could figure out how to sum up the lengths between set start- and endpoints, but I don't know how to start with using these with string attributes. Can I do this with pandas ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, create a column that will serve to indicate where each 0.1km-section ：

```
df['label'] = df['Start'].apply(lambda x: int(x/0.1))
print(df)
   Start    End Arrtib  Length  label
0  0.000  0.030      K   0.030      0
1  0.030  0.036      K   0.006      0
2  0.036  0.082      K   0.046      0
3  0.082  0.091      H   0.009      0
4  0.091  0.096      H   0.005      0
5  0.096  0.100      K   0.004      0
6  0.100  0.121      K   0.021      1
7  0.121  0.123      K   0.002      1
```

Then obtain the attribute  unique value of each 0.1km-section ：

```
unique  = df.groupby('label').agg({'Arrtib': lambda x: np.unique(x,return_counts=True)})
print(unique)
                 Arrtib
label                  
0      ([H, K], [2, 4])
1            ([K], [2])
```

Finally get the most common attribute and percentage of the total 0.1km-section:

```
unique['mostcommon'] = unique['Arrtib'].map(lambda x:x[0][-1])
unique['percentage '] = unique['Arrtib'].map(lambda x:x[1][-1]/x[1].sum())
print(unique)
                 Arrtib mostcommon  percentage 
label                                          
0      ([H, K], [2, 4])          K     0.666667
1            ([K], [2])          K     1.000000
```